# [tensorflow]install tensorflow-gpu with import error as Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

Use the command '`pip install --ingore-installed -- upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`' to install `tensorflow-gpu` for Python3.6 as official instruction.

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux
```

And it seems like installed successfully as shown

[image: installed successfully]

but when test in python with "`import tensorflow`", it comes with error as `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`.
[image: Segmentation fault]

When using the similar to install tensorflow for cpu, there is no problem.

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and my Anaconda env "tf-gpu" is new built, without other python lib to disturb.

I didn't find similar problem and solution as import to cause dump. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using incompatible CUDA and/or cuDNN.
Follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems) to see which version to use.